# SwiftUI: ViewModifier callback when view is completely removed, like onDisappear but called only once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

the `onAppear` `onDisappear` modifiers can be called multiple times while the view is part of the hierarchy.

I know that there is a trick to make an `onLoad` ViewModifier like so

```swift
extension View {
    func onLoad(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ViewDidLoadModifier(action: action))
    }
}

struct ViewDidLoadModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var viewDidLoad = false
    let action: (() -> Void)?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                if viewDidLoad == false {
                    viewDidLoad = true
                    action?()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

From the above code, `onLoad` will only be called once

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello View")
            .onAppear {
                // may print multiple times
                print("onAppear")
            }
            .onLoad {
               // only prints once
               // when the view first appears in the hierarchy
               print("onLoad")
            }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have an `onUnLoad` ViewModifier?

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello View")
            .onDisappear {
                // may print multiple times
                print("onDisappear")
            }
            .onUnLoad {
               // only prints once,
               // when the view is completely removed
               print("onUnLoad")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of external action are you trying to do in an onUnload?

Comment: @malhal Analytics. We need to know when the user has left the screen

Comment: Trying to do this is a code smell. It sounds like you're trying to force SwiftUI to behave imperatively. I would you encourage you to look upstream and find a better architecture that doesn't require this workaround.

Comment: @DavidB. Encouragement is one thing, giving me actual help is another. I need a way to know that the user has navigated away from this screen for good

Comment: @flopshot It's difficult to provide more help without some context around why you are doing this. It seems like onDismiss should suffice. If onDismiss is being called when the user hasn't navigated away from the view then maybe that is the issue that should be handled.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to create an `onUnload` ViewModifier wrapping a `UIView` in a `UIViewRepresentable` and using its `willMove(toSuperview:)` event

```swift
struct ViewDidUnloadModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: () -> Void

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            ViewDidUnloadRepresentable(action: action)
            content
        }

    }
}

struct ViewDidUnloadRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let action: () -> Void

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> DidUnloadView {
        return DidUnloadView(action: action)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: DidUnloadView, context: Context) {
    }
}

final class DidUnloadView: UIView {

    let action: () -> Void

    init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        if newSuperview == nil {
            action()
        }
        super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
    }

}
```

In UIKit, if a view's `willMove(toSuperview:)` method is called and `toSuperview` is nil, it means that the UIView is being completely removed from the hierarchy.
The code below will now work as expected

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello View")
            .onDisappear {
                // may print multiple times
                print("onDisappear")
            }
            .onUnload {
               // only prints once when removed, EUREKA!
               print("onUnload")
            }
    }
}
```